# How to save a file in a changing location c#

Tags: c#

I have a report that I created in Excel using c#. Every user will be downloading it form their individual computers. There for, making the saving and opening operation of my program difficult. I want to be able to save it to the computers documents location. Here is what I have as far as relavent code goes.

```
string subPath = "Documents/Reports";

bool isExists = Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(subPath));

if (!isExists)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(subPath));

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("Reports\\" + filename, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();
```

Any ideas on how to create a path that will always work with any pc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve the machine's local documents folder path using the `Enironment.GetFolderPath` method:

```
string subPath = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(
        Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Reports";
```

Comment: It makes it a physical path I need to a virtual one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method and `Combine` it into a real path:

```
    String subPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),"Reports");
```